# In typescript 2.0, how to have a single declaration file for modules not available in the @types npm namespace (DefinitelyTyped repo)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

In a typescript project I need to use the [bytewise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytewise) npm module. This package does not have a type definition in the DefinitelyTyped npm namespace, so I can't use the method described in typescript documentation:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/bytewise
```

Since there's no type declaration for this module, it is not possible to use it, as `tsc` complains with: `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bytewise'`.

To fix the issue, I have written a declaration file for `bytewise` and added it to `node_modules/@types/bytewise/index.d.ts`, which worked perfectly.

However, this is a tedious common pattern: I use a small npm library for which there are no @types declaration, create a directory under `node_modules/@types`, add an `index.d.ts` containing the declarations for the library, then git force/add that file(since `node_modules` is ignored by default).

Clearly I don't plan to maintain those declarations forever under my private `node_modules` directory, eventually I'd like to contribute them back to DefinitelyTyped so they can be installed more easily later, but rather than creating a separate directory/file for each library I'm using, I'd rather have a single `vendor.d.ts` file in the root of my project with all declarations not available on npm. Something like this(this is what I have in my project ATM):

```
import bl = require("bl");
import {Stream} from "stream";

declare module "bytewise" {
  export function encode(val: any): bl;
  export function decode(val: bl): any;
  export const buffer: boolean;
  export const type: string;
}

declare module "JSONStream" {
  export function parse(patternOrPath?: string): Stream;
  export function stringify(open?: string, sep?: string, close?: string);
}
```

The question is: How do I make these declarations available to all files in my project? I have tried modifying `tsconfig.json` to include it before the entry point:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "out",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
    "vendor.d.ts",
    "index.ts"    
  ]
}
```

but still get `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bytewise'.` in the files where I have `import * as bytewise from "bytewise";`. I also tried adding a `/// <reference path="..." />` comment pointing to `vendor.d.ts` but got the same error. Do I really need to have a separate declaration file for each npm module or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Just include `vendor.d.ts` in your project, with no special configuration, but with one key change: move the two imports at the top to just after the line

```
declare module "bytewise" {
```

Any exports or imports outside of declarations will make this fail, with cryptic messages like:

`Error:(3, 16) TS2665:Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'bytewise' resolves to an untyped module at 'my-project/node_modules/bytewise/bytewise.js'.`